# MemcacheShimEmulator error

Tags: azure, memcached, azure-diagnostics

I have a solution in development that has been hosted on Azure and runs fine but now I want to add memcache to ensure scalability. I add Windows Azure Caching 1.8.1.0 and then add Windows Azure Caching Memcache Shim 1.8.0.0 via Nuget. I have the endpoint of memcache_default with an internal port of 11212 (to avoid port conflict because 11211 is in use) and I have caching enabled in my web role.

When I run my application, the web role cycles and I get a number of errors in the event log repeating on each cycle...

First....

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          08/04/2013 21:11:56
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DRAKE
Description:
Application: MemcacheShimInstaller.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MemcacheShimInstaller.MemcacheShimInstaller.Main(System.String[])
```

Second....

```
Faulting application name: MemcacheShimInstaller.exe, version: 1.0.4797.0, time stamp: 0x506f41f4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b8479b
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009e5d
Faulting process id: 0x1f40
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce349550d2f050
Faulting application path: C:\DevProjects\MyWebRole\csx\Debug\roles\MyWebRole\approot\bin\WindowsAzure.Caching.MemcacheShim\MemcacheShimInstaller.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 90968bce-a088-11e2-9abd-00266c50c008
```

Third....

```
Application: MemcacheShimEmulator.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MemcacheShimEmulator.MemcacheShimEmulator.Main(System.String[])
```

Finally...

```
Faulting application name: MemcacheShimEmulator.exe, version: 1.0.4797.0, time stamp: 0x506f41f6
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b8479b
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009e5d
Faulting process id: 0x7ac
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce349551b479fd
Faulting application path: C:\DevProjects\MyWebRole\csx\Debug\roles\MyWebRole\bin\WindowsAzure.Caching.MemcacheShim\MemcacheShimEmulator.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 910f8e24-a088-11e2-9abd-00266c50c008
```

I am trying to find more logging information but I don't know where to look. If I create a brand new cloud service solution and configure it as best I can it runs successfully so how can I find what the cause of this problem is?